# About MySql and array for php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql database table. It is storing time and temperature in evey minute.

```
time temp
00:00 27
00:01 27.1
00:02 27.1
```

I want to put above two fields into an array. I tried following code, but It only print out the last row. What's wrong in it?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `XXX` where date='".$today."' order by time DESC limit 10";

$sqlQ=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sqlQ)){
$arr=array($rows['time']=>$rows['tempOut']);

}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
$arr=array($rows['time']=>$rows['tempOut']);
```

with

```
$arr[$rows['time']] = $rows['tempOut'];
```

You don't need `$arr = array();` before `while(...`.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a fresh instance of `array` every time inside the loop therefore it only saves the last row.

It will be more like

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `XXX` where date='".$today."' order by time DESC limit 10";

$sqlQ=mysql_query($sql);

$arr = array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sqlQ)){
     $arr[$rows['time']] = $rows['tempOut'];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Note: `mysql` extension is deprecated use `mysqli`